# does maigo work as a name for a musical artist

Tags: translation

I have been pursuing a career in music under the name “Maigo” and I even have the kanji writing of the word tattooed on myself.  Would this make sense in japan

Comment: This is off-topic because it's opinion-based.

Comment: Do you mean "maiko"? Because that's a lot more music-related than "maigo", and I'm unsure if there's an over-generalization of rendaku (voiced second kanji) or not.

Answer (score 6):

"Maigo" (迷子 in kanji) is a common Japanese word which normally refers to [this](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%BF%B7%E5%AD%90), a lost child which you would see in a department store. Sometimes it can refer to someone who got lost in general.

[image: 迷子]

Is this what you have in mind (and on your skin)? Whether you like it or not, a Japanese speaker who heard "maigo" would probably wonder "Does this name have anything to do with lost children?"

- If your name has nothing to do with 迷子, you don't have to worry much. A coincidence like this happens often.
- Or was your name really taken from 迷子? 迷子 is a rather prosaic Japanese word, and it sounds a bit odd as a stage name. Still, being a bit odd is not necessarily bad, so ultimately it's up to you.